# Could you solve co-RE problems with a halting oracle?

Tags: computability, halting-problem, oracle-machines

The halting problem is $RE$ complete. With an oracle for the halting problem could you decide problems in $co RE$ with an oracle for RE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In general - for a language $L$ an oracle to $L$ is equivalent to an oracle of $\overline L$.

Since the complement of the halting problem is co-RE complete (it is immediate from the fact that the halting is RE complete), then an oracle to it can solve all co-RE.